# Save Image to sandbox from UIImage in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiimage

I am showing very big size images in UITableView, because of this my app is getting crashed after some time. Now i want to resize the image and save it to disk. can some one help me resizing the image from NSData/UIImage and saving saving it to the disk.

I got the code to resize the image from UIImage, so as the result i have my resized in image in UIImage object, how to save it to iphone sandbox.

Thanks,

Answer (score 30):

Here is code to save to the Documents directory on iOS that is from working code.

```
// Convert UIImage to JPEG
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1); // 1 is compression quality

// Identify the home directory and file name    
NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.jpg"]; 

// Write the file.  Choose YES atomically to enforce an all or none write. Use the NO flag if partially written files are okay which can occur in cases of corruption
[imgData writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Awesome answer, it helped me.  Is it simple (one line of code) to access that data again?  Or should I ask another question on stack?

Comment: @KKendall you can just do `[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:]` or `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]`

Comment: JPEG is a lossy format, so I recommend using UIImagePNGRepresentation instead.  You will have quality issues if you write/read the image to/from disk repeatedly.

Answer (score 4):

You're asking 'how do I write a file' right?

I guess there is a touch of complication in that you probably want to write into the Library/Caches directory, so when the phone gets backed up you don't save those files.

Get the root of the app folder w/ `NSHomeDirectory()` and then append Library/Caches.

You can write an NSData to the fs w/ a method on NSData. If you have a UIImage, you can do `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation` to get data.

Comment: You probably want to use 
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *cachesDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

Rather than appending 'Library/Caches' yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);`

```
CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFMutableDataRef)imgData, NULL);
NSDictionary *metadata = [(NSDictionary *) CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source,0,NULL)autorelease];
NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.jpg"];
[imageMutableData writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];
```

It will copy your image to documents folder in sandbox with name `Test.jpg`.

If you want to do it for PNG you can try `UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);`