# Base64 to image with given format

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uikit, base64

I have used the following  to save base64 image data.

```
NSData *data=[NSData dataFromBase64String:base64];
UIImage *image= [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

It is always saved as a png type.

How can I set the type of the image other than png (jpeg etc.) ?

Comment: See the top answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150911/save-image-to-sandbox-from-uiimage-in-iphone

Answer (score 2):

After getting the `UIImage` you will have to convert it back into data with different format then you can get **png** and **jpg or jpeg** `UIImage`.

```
NSData *data1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0); // 1.0 is for original you can compress it by passing the float b/w 0-1
NSData *data2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

UIImage *jpgImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data1];
UIImage *pngImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data2];
```

Or you can also write `data` with image extensions in documents directory.

```
[data writeToFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.jpeg"] atomically:YES];
// It will save this image as jpeg. But would not work for all formats.
```

**Edit:**
See this link [How to convert .jpg image to .bmp format using Objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369958/how-to-convert-jpg-image-to-bmp-format-using-objective-c).

Comment: only these two types are available in ios?

Comment: What formats do you want ?

Comment: You can't convert it directly ... See edit part.

Comment: Or you can also googling for that ... https://www.google.co.in/search?biw=1019&bih=625&noj=1&sclient=psy-ab&q=convert++image+to+bmp+%2B+ios&oq=convert++image+to+bmp+%2B+ios&gs_l=serp.12...168784.168784.1.169641.1.1.0.0.0.0.213.213.2-1.1.0....0...1c.1.24.serp..1.0.0.id5I-BUkqi4

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`UIImageJPEGRepresentation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageJPEGRepresentation)?